# Is there a point in increasing my view range over 445m in World of Tanks?

Tags: world-of-tanks

The question pretty much says it all. I know that the maximum view range is 445m which can be easily reached with some tanks (FCM 36 Pak 40 for example). Is there a point in increasing it any further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When calculating spotting range, i.e. the range at which you would see a particular target, the camo rating of enemy tanks will knock a tank's view range back down, so there is every reason to increase view range in order to maximize your spotting range.  There is no set maximum view range, though the maximum effective view range that you can achieve (at the time of writing this answer) is 606.79m.

For instance, let's compare the spotting range of two tanks against an enemy tank with an effective camo rating of 50%.  Tank A has an effective view range of 445m, while Tank B has an effective view range of 500m.  Tank A's spotting range against the enemy tank is 247.5m...math: 445 - ((445-50)*0.5).  Tank B's spotting range against the same enemy tank is 275m...math: 500 - ((500-50)*0.5).

See http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/View_Range_%26_Camouflage_(WoT) for more details.

Comment: Some tanks, like the Pak40, can gain a lot of XP through spotting once you reach the right spot on the map.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a point of maximizing your view range

though the max cap for spotting range is 445m iirc, having more than that actually counteracts enemy's camo, hence making it easier to spot targets with slightly worse camo values easier.